# getBBox function returns object with zero-valued properties from dynamically created text SVG node

Tags: javascript, svg

I'd like to get `width` of dynamically created text SVG node. Here's my code snippet.

```
var textSvgElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text');
textSvgElement.setAttribute('style', '12px');
textSvgElement.setAttribute('x', '10');
textSvgElement.setAttribute('y', '20');
textSvgElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('some text'));
var textSvgElementDataObj = textSvgElement.getBBox();
```

But `textSvgElementDataObj` variable always contains object with zero-valued properties like on image:

[image]

Could anyone give me some pieces of advice how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks! It works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach the textSvgElement to the document first.